# Why wont this code display content inside of a scrollPane with the three button at bottom

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have set the JFrame to visible at the end of my view class and am not sure as to why my custom JPanels are still not visible.I am trying to simplify code and avoid a huge View class, all while implementing good object oriented programming style.  The JButtons at the bottom of the JFrame in my main panel are visible. I have tried to just add the custom panels to the frame but they still are not visible.

I have tried to set everything to visible and only adding the custom JPanels to the JFrame.

```
public View(Main pMain) 
{
    setMain(pMain);

    panelClientInfo = new JClientPanel();
    panelPaymentInfo = new JPaymentPanel();
    panelJobDescription = new JJobPanel();
    panelAgreement = new JAgreementPanel();
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    panelSecondary = new JPanel();
    panelMain = new JPanel();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelMain);

    panelSecondary.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelSecondary, 
    BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelSecondary.add(panelClientInfo);
    panelSecondary.add(panelJobDescription);
    panelSecondary.add(panelPaymentInfo);
    panelSecondary.add(panelAgreement);
    panelMain.add(panelSecondary, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelMain.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panelMain.add(submitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panelMain.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    scrollPane.add(panelMain);
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);


    setTitle("G.C. Septic Services Contract Drafter");
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(scrollPane);

    setVisible(true);


}

/**Here is a custom JPanel that I am trying to use*/
package contractDrafter;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JAgreementPanel extends JPanel
{
JPanel panelMain;
JLabel submitterLabel;
JTextField submitterText;

public JAgreementPanel() 
{
    panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    submitterLabel = new JLabel("Submitter Name: ");
    submitterText = new JTextField("e.g: Calvin M. Cox", 30);

    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    panelMain.add(submitterLabel);
    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    panelMain.add(submitterText);
    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
}
```

}

I want this program to display the different JPanels so that all my Mother in Law has to do is type in some values into the completed program and it will write the file for her, to reduce the workload on her arthritic hands. I am hoping to see the JPanels end up on the frame in a semi-neat to neat way so that she can  scroll up and down on the frame and enter the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageofDesiredGui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdHDN.png)

So I finally figured out what it was.I would like to thank @OverLoadedBurden for his fast reply and helpfulness. I will only provide one custom JPanel class because the rest are so similar that it would be unnecessary. Whenever I was creating the custom JPanels the panels were not displaying because I was adding the content to a panel contained within the Custom JPanel. For example, in the old code I wrote:

```
public JAgreementPanel() 
{
    panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    submitterLabel = new JLabel("Submitter Name: ");
    submitterText = new JTextField("e.g: Calvin M. Cox", 30);

    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    //This is where the error exists
    panelMain.add(submitterLabel);
    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    //This is where the error exists
    panelMain.add(submitterText);
    panelMain.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
  }
Whereas I should have been adding the desired content of the panel to the custom 
panel 
itself. This is the new correctly functioning code: 
public JAgreementPanel() 
    {
        panelMain = new JPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        submitterLabel = new JLabel("Submitter Name: ");
        submitterText = new JTextField("e.g: Calvin M. Cox", 30);
        //this could be also written as "this.add(submitterLabel)"
        add(submitterLabel);
        add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        add(submitterText);
        add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        setVisible(true);
    }
This could also be accomplished with the code comments as well. I will also include 
the updated view constructor that is called to create the gui:
public View(Main pMain) 
{

    setMain(pMain);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    panelSecondary = new JPanel();
    panelMain = new JPanel();


    panelSecondary.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelSecondary, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panelSecondary.add(new JAgreementPanel());

    panelSecondary.add(new JClientPanel());

    panelSecondary.add(new JJobPanel());

    panelSecondary.add(new JPaymentPanel());

    panelMain.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    panelMain.add(panelSecondary);

    JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();

    panelButtons.add(exitButton);
    panelButtons.add(clearButton);
    panelButtons.add(submitButton);

    panelMain.add(panelButtons);


    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelMain);


    scrollPane.setVisible(true);

    add(panelMain);

    setTitle("G.C. Septic Services Contract Drafter");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code contains a lot of missing classes !! when you post your code at least work with super classes so we can understand what is the deal with it .

any how

> I have tried to just add the custom panels to the frame but they still are not visible.

this do conflict with your code mate !!
in the code

```
panelMain.add(panelSecondary, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panelMain.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panelMain.add(submitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panelMain.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

the the constraints that you passes belong to `BorderLayout` on the other hand you haven't set the layout to `BorderLayout` so by default it's `FlowLayout`

and again even if it was `BorderLayout` to add in the same "border" will cover the last component in that border !

you haven't uploaded an image but i can imagine the buttons where horizontally aligned at the center, and that because of the default `FlowLayout` layout of the `JPanel` .

> I am hoping to see the JPanels end up on the frame in a semi-neat to neat way so that she can scroll up and down on the frame and enter the necessary information.

well , you are making the scroll pane contains the panel's and the button's , and that is just plain wrong (at least in your case of designing).

what you should do is something like

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel slidingPanel = new JPanel ();
slidingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(slidingPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXSIS));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPanel (slidingPanel);
f.getContentPane().add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
//then add all of your panels in the slidingpanel
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
//i can't give you a hint on this , it's almost just designer choice for how you want your buttons to layout
//but add them to the south !!
f.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

and if you still need some extra hands on your project for your family i will gladly help  you but stack overflow is not the place for it , upload your project in a private github repo , or if you already have one invite me,my account is with the same details as my account in here mate ;).

Comment: I would love to connect to you elsewhere! I have tried the code you suggested and it still is not displaying anything. My github username: is tylerdixon117

Comment: right now am not valid environment for coding , but i looked you up and this project is not on any of your repo's ! upload the project so i can check it out @TylerJDixon

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, I will get back to you as soon as I can plug it in to eclipse. I'm at work at the moment. Thanks again for the help!